# Excel streaming reader consuming large CPU Consumption

Tags: java, apache-poi, xls

I am trying to upload 100k records from xlsx file and using Excel Streaming Reader to iterate excel
It was failing in QA server but made changes

```
StreamingReader.builder()
                .sstCacheSize(100)
                .open(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath)));
```

made it work but it is consuming large CPU resources and other users using particular environment complaining of performance hit.

Any suggestions would appreciate

Comment: If you want it to be faster, I would suggest using a simpler file format; e.g. CSV files.  Alternatively, spend some time researching faster alternatives to POI.  (And be prepared to live with the concomitant downsides ... which might include paying for a license.)  P.S.: recommendations are off-topic, so don't ask.

Comment: Reading 100k rows via SAX using the Apache POI helpers can be done very quickly and with pretty minimal memory footprint. Maybe swap to that? And/or check what you are doing with the 100,000 records you read in, maybe processing that is actually the perfomance issue?

Comment: I checked only reading part is consuming loads of  CPU .

Comment: Could it be your are running low on memory and cpu load is caused by GC? If so, passing a higher value for -Xmx might help. If you are on unix/linux, a quick workaround to reduce complaints from other users would be to start your program using the `nice` command.

Comment: `.open(new File(filePath))` uses less memory than reading from an InputStream - if you read from an InputStream, the POI and excel-streaming-reader will waste CPU and memory doing prep work to access the zip file elements in the xlsx file